# How to change the background color of the section below tab bar?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to change background color of the section which is below the tab bar but I don't know what the name of it is.

[image]

I tried with some option in tab bar but it does not work.

Comment: just look at the list of theme colors and discard most of them because there name definitely does not match and then you are left with just a few names to try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is controlled by the `breadcrumb` properties found in `workbench.colorCustomizations`:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "breadcrumb.background": "#ff0000",
    "breadcrumb.foreground": "#00ff26"
  }
```

[image: image showing breadcrumb bar color changes]