# How can I change the color of the top bar that holds tabs and other actions and the breadcrumb bar in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes, background-color, workbench

How can I change the color of the top bar that holds tabs and other actions and the breadcrumb bar in VS Code?

[image: the place of arrow mark to change the color]

i tried toolbar and statusbar to change, but it didn't work.

Comment: Note: in the `Developer: Toggle Developer Tools`, the classnames of those HTML elements are `tabs-and-actions-container` and `tabs-breadcrumbs` respectively.

Comment: See duplicates at https://stackoverflow.com/a/69043089/836330 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/74682740/836330.

Answer (score 0):

The UI element IDs you are looking for are mainly the following:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[Name Of Your Theme Here]": {
        "tab.activeBackground": "#ff0000",
        "tab.inactiveBackground": "#ff0000",
        "breadcrumb.background": "#ff0000",
        "editorGroupHeader.tabsBackground": "#ff0000"
    }
}
```

You'll need to figure out what the colour values you want to use are from your extension's source files. See the extension's package.json file and the `"contributes"` > `"themes"` field to find out what file the theme's JSON file is, then read that file and look for the above UI element IDs and what colour values they have.

See also https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customizing-a-color-theme.